# How can I access React Native Bridge?

Tags: android, react-native

Since React Native is open-source, I want to be able to access the `react-native` bridge, and learn from that or maybe tweak it for our own framework, but I don't even know how to access that. is there anyone who can help me?
I am talking about the bridge between `react-native` code and `native android (Java) code.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) open source code on GitHub.

The project is broken up into a couple groups, the big ones are Android (ReactAndroid), iOS (React), and Common (ReactCommon). You can find a lot of the Android Bridge code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge), and some iOS code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/React/CxxBridge). I would suggest picking Android or iOS and diving into the React Native code.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I'll take a look at it. Do you have any hint by any chance about how the bridge works with android? any source code you may know?

Comment: I have played around with it a little bit and the first step is creating a [RN Host](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactNativeHost.java). Then you can create a context on the host by getting its [InstanceManager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManager.java). From the Context you can get the CatalystInstance which gets you closer to the bridge.

Comment: Do you know how does the bridge takes the javascript code and converts it to native android(java)?

Comment: The javascript code isn't converted into native code. The javascript code runs in its own context, like a Javascript virtual machine, using JavascriptCore. It's running and communicating over the bridge via events, etc. To see how objects are passed back and forth, see [ReadableMap](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableMap.java) and dig into its implementation. ReadableMap in java correlates to a JS Object.

Comment: Thanks again. What I want to do is that instead of taking this .js (index.android.js) files locally, take it from some Web server, so load the .js files from web server to react native. Would you please help me with that?

Comment: You should take a look at CodePush from Microsoft. It does this: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push